# is there any upper limit on relevance score in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

I intend to normalize the relevance score returned by queries( using more_like_this query ) in elasticsearch. Is there any limit on maximum possible relevance score.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no there isn't.

Why do you need to normalize the relevance score? What is your use case?